# How to compile webpack externals js lib to another file

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I according to [this article](http://jslog.com/2014/10/02/react-with-webpack-part-1/) to write a reactjs app, but it mentioned `webpack's externals` configuration item, these third part lib should not pack in our bundle.js.

What you see, in article, **reactjs included in `index.html`**.

I can do that in development environment, but how to compile it to a separate file in production?(may also have other dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet, in your webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: 'index.js',
        vendors: ['react', 'flux']  //assuming you use react and flux, add as many npm packages here as you want
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', './js/vendors.js') //this line means put everything defined in vendors to a file named vendors.js
    ]
};
```

You can find a similar example of this [at the bottom of the offical doc page](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization)